# blender 2.54 beta command line issues

Tags: blender

When I run this command from with the dir where .blend is located:

blender -d -b test2.blend -o //output -e 1

it does not work. I tried both in linux 64 bit and vista 64bit. It does not generate rendered output file. .blend file is just very simple scene with cube and cylnder.

For vista here is some of debug info:

RNA_string_set: OperatorProperties.data_path not found.
RNA_boolean_set: OperatorProperties.reverse not found.
search for unknown operator CONSOLE_OT_execute, CONSOLE_OT_execute
search for unknown operator CONSOLE_OT_execute, CONSOLE_OT_execute
search for unknown operator CONSOLE_OT_autocomplete, CONSOLE_OT_autocomplete
read blend: C:\docs\blender\models\test2.blend
read file C:\docs\blender\models\test2.blend
  Version 254 sub 0

ordered
 OBCylinder
 OBCube
 OBLamp
 OBCamera
*bpy stats* - tot exec: 4,  tot run: 0.0000sec,  average run: 0.000003sec,  tot
usage 0.0026%

Blender quit
press enter key to exit...

For linux the output is:

:  ref:6  ptr:0x667e170 type:type
 :  ref:6  ptr:0x667ede0 type:type
 :  ref:6  ptr:0x667f5f0 type:type
 :  ref:6  ptr:0x667fe90 type:type
 :  ref:6  ptr:0x6680390 type:type
 :  ref:6  ptr:0x661d640 type:RNAMeta
*bpy stats* - tot exec: 4,  tot run: 0.0000sec,  average run: 0.000000sec,  tot usage 0.0005%

Blender quit

Any one with blender 3d background can help?

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the option e with f fixed the problem.